# Wrong calculation in the sum of the value of dynamic columns with delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a restaurant order form where in i input the values on textboxes and will display on the list with the subtotals and total after button click using Ajax.

my problem is that the sum of the subtotals gives me wrong value 
and doesnt change if i click the delete button.

| qty | price|subtotal | 
| 10 | 3.50  | 35.00 | 
| 10 | 9.00  | 90.00 |

Total : 180.00  instead of 125.00

wherein it calculated the number of rows x last subtotal value.

Please see the code snippet attached TIA!

```js
var impo = document.getElementById("imp_text");
var quant = document.getElementById("qta");

$(document).on("click", "table.dynatable button.delete-row", function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});

function loaddata() {
  var importo = $("#imp_text").val();
  var quantita = $("#qta").val();
  var totale = importo * quantita;
  var desc_importo = "Altro ";
  var markup = "<tr><td><span class='sum_qta' name='sum_qta'>" + quantita + "</span></td><td>" + desc_importo + "</td><td>" + importo + "</td><td class='subtot' >" + totale + "</td><td><button type='button' class='delete-row'>X</button></td></tr>";

  $("table.dynatable tbody").append(markup);

  var $tblrows = $("#tableordine tbody tr");
  $tblrows.each(function(index) {
    var $tblrow = $(this);

    if (!isNaN(totale)) {

      $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(totale.toFixed(2));
      var grandTotal = 0;

      $(".subtot").each(function() {
        var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
        grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
      });

      $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    }

  });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <font color="black">

    <table class="table dynatable" id="tableordine">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Import</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>subtotal</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>

    <hr/> Totale:<input type="text" class="grdtot">

<hr/>
    <FORM name="Keypad" action="">
      Import : <input name="ReadOut" id="imp_text" type="Text" size=24 value=" "> Quantity : <input type="text" name="readqta" id="qta" value="1" />
      <p>

        <input type="button" id="entraordine" class="add-row menu_button" value="Entra" onclick="loaddata();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to first write your own button click event handler rather than using the `onclick=""` html attribute. Should be something like: 
`$("body").on("click", "#entraordine", function(){
    //code here
});`

Comment: also why do you have `val(totale.toFixed(2))` instead of just `.val()` in `$tblrow.find('.subtot').val(totale.toFixed(2));` ??

Comment: @N.Ivanov so that i could refer the value of the class  .subtot as totale and toFIxed(2) for the  decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/tbskqrby/

```
$(document).on("click", "table.dynatable button.delete-row", function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    rowCal();
});

rowCal = function(){
    var $tblrows = $("#tableordine tbody tr");
    $tblrows.each(function(index) {
        var $tblrow = $(this);

        if (!isNaN(totale)) {

            $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(totale.toFixed(2));
            var grandTotal = 0;

            $(".subtot").each(function() {
                var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
            });

            $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
       }

   });
}
```

Comment: the total value changes when delete button is clicked now but it gives the wrong value of the Total

Comment: @Shiladitya Could you explain why this is the solution?

Comment: @OFBrc Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/tbskqrby/1/ . The problem lies with your  var stval = parseFloat($(this).val()); . I changed it to var stval = parseFloat($(this).text()); to get the value.